# How to insert 2 php files to code snippet?

Tags: php, wordpress, code-snippets

I found the following site https://funnelpress.com/elementor-post-not-found-content/

It has two codes but I want two insert them in the 'code snippets' plugin in wordpress.
Can somebody help me how to insert them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) is an easy method to run [PHP](https://www.php.net/) code into your [WordPress](https://wordpress.org/download/) site. There is no hassle managing PHP code. any time active code & deactivate code there.

Now we learn how to insert code into WordPress via the code snippets plugin. We can follow some steps to do the task. So, let's start.

1. At first log in to your WordPress website and install the Code Snippets plugin and Active it.
   [image]
2. Find Snippets Menu and click Add New. After Clicking shows a page like a screenshot.
   [image]
3. Provide a snippet title and paste code into the code section.
   [image: List item]
4. After Paste code then select where your code run. I think nothing changed here. Default select Run snippet everywhere.
5. We can set code priority, description & tags. We can note down about code in the description & set tag. Tags are separated by a comma(,).

   [image: List item]
6. After finishing all steps then click Save Changes and Active button.

   [image: List item]
7. After clicking the button then show a message Snippet added and actived.

   [image: List item]

Comment: By just copy pasting the code nothing happens to the Post widget in Elementor. So what do I have to change?